# How to check inheritance in generics with inherited parameter_

Tags: delphi, generics

I have 2 class hierarchies:

1.

```
TObject
  --TAmObject
    --TAmField
    --TAmFarm
```

2.

```
TObjectList<T: TAmObject>
  --TAmObjectList<T: TAmObject>
     --TAmFieldList
     --TAmFarmList
```

I have some of the of the object linked to TTreeView's nodes.

Then I have a task to check:

```
if TObject(node.Data) is TAmObject
```

or

```
if TObject(node.Data) is TAmObjectList<TAmObject>
```

First check is good and brings me no problems.
With the second one I have some difficulties.

Pls show me way to make the check.
For example I have TamFarmList linked to node.

Then compiled says me:

```
TObject(node.Data) is TAmObjectList<TAmObject> = FALSE
```

but

```
TObject(node.Data) is TAmObjectList<TAmFarm> = TRUE
```

But I need common check for all lists.

Pls show me the way. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem of covariance that Delphi does not support. Since generic types do not provide reflection of their type parameters you have to find some other ways.

One solution I have used over the past is to do some string parsing of the type name and then use RTTI to do what C# reflection for example is capable of. It is not perfect but has done the job pretty well in the past.

Here is some example code using Spring4D for that.

```
uses
  Spring.Helpers,
  Spring.Reflection;

...

var
  t: TRttiType;
begin
  t := TType.GetType(TObject(node.Data).ClassType);
  if (t.GetGenericTypeDefinition = 'TAmObjectList<>')
    and (t.GetGenericArguments[0].AsInstance.MetaclassType.InheritsFrom(TAmObject)) then
```

This works if your instance directly is a `TAmObjectList<T>` where T is `TAmObject`. If you want to have it work for descendant list classes you will have to walk up the inheritance hierarchy on your instance performing the `GetGenericTypeDefinition` check on it.

Comment: Thanks as always for your anser. Should I take last version of the Spring4D library? I ask it because I have Current version: 1.0 (2014-04-01)... and I can not find the methods there.

Comment: What you have is the 1.0 release version. While it has the `GetGenericArguments` method it does not have the `GetGenericTypeDefinition` one. You can use the latest develop version or just take the method from there and integrate it into your version.

Comment: With some small changes in your code it works for me. Thanks a lot for the help.